# Multi-Line Sed Replace

Tags: linux, sed, find-and-replace

Consider the following text (incidentally, part of a MySQL dump):

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `full_index` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

I would like to remove the `FULLTEXT` key, and I also want to remove the trailing comma on the line above so that the SQL remains valid.

Can anyone come up with (and explain) a `sed` recipe to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### AWK answer

With your sample text in a file named `sql`, the following pattern (with line breaks and indentation for clarity):

```
awk -v skip=1 '{
    if (skip) { skip=0 }
    else {
        if (/FULLTEXT KEY/) { skip=1; sub(/,$/, "", prevline) }
        print prevline
    }
    prevline=$0
}
END { print prevline }' sql
```

produces:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Explanation:

- We implement "lookahead" by only printing the *previously* encountered line at every iteration, after inspecting the current line.
- If the current line contains the `FULLTEXT KEY` marker, we set a flag to skip printing this line during the next iteration. We also remove the trailing comma on the previous line that is about to be printed.
- We skip printing an empty initial line (before `prevline` has been set) by initially setting `skip` to `1` ("true").
- We make sure to print the last line by ending the script with an extra `prevline` print. Note that the current implementation assumes that this last line is not a line at risk of being skipped, i.e. that it does not contain the `FULLTEXT KEY` marker.

#### Original (incomplete) `sed` answer

*This answer is incomplete and certainly in most cases incorrect, since `sed` will consume the input stream too quickly for the intended result when doing multiline matching -- as pointed out in the comments, it will only work for matches on even numbered rows! `sed` does not have "true" lookahead functionality, so we would be better off using Python/Perl/etc., or indeed AWK as above.*

With your sample text in a file named `sql`, the following pattern:

```
$ sed 'N; s/,\n  FULLTEXT.*//' sql
```

produces:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Explanation:

- `N` enables multiline matching.
- `\n` represents a line break.
- `s/pattern/replacement/` is the standard replacement syntax.
- `.*` will match anything to the end of the current line.

Comment: Only works if your match is on even line. This wont work if "FULLTEXT" is on line 7 instead of line 6!

Comment: @nexayq: Good catch! I cannot use `sed` in the fashion I attempted above. Since the "test case" worked by pure chance and no further feedback was given at the time of the answer some three years ago, I assumed `sed` had some intelligent stream backtracking ability in its multiline mode, and thus never reviewed my answer further. I add a more verbose but probably also more straightforward AWK solution as a substitute. It is most likely still possible to solve with `sed`, but then probably with more work than with AWK (or even Perl, Python, shell script, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Managing two lines with sed is not that difficult.
Just keep two lines in pattern space.

- $!N : this command append a line in pattern space.
- P : print the first line in pattern space
- D : delete the first line in pattern space and start new cycle (without read a line)
  if remain only one line then it behave like "d" command ( that is read a line and start new cycle )

```
sed -n '$!N; s/,[[:space:]]*FULLTEXT KEY.*// ;P;D'
```